# Windows Forms App Has Bad Proportions on Windows 7

Tags: winforms, graphics, windows-7, c#-3.0, windows-xp

I've got a C# 3.0 Windows Forms app built with VS2008 (previously ported from C# 1.1) that looks fine on a WinXP 32bit PC but has jacked proportions on Win7 64bit laptop.

I'm finding references to the lack of support on Win7 for Tahoma 8, which the app uses. Do I need to redesign my dialog using Tahoma 9 to get it to display well on all 3 OSes?

Here are my initial measurements (cm) of a group box containing radio buttons and a button:

OS, Resolution, GroupBox HxW, RadioButton HxW

XP, 1024 x 768, 7.5 x 6.75, 0.75 x 4.4

[image: Group Box with radios--XP]
[image: Button--XP]

7, 1024 x 768, 6.8 x 6.3, 0.8 x 5.0

7, 1680 x 1050, 4.9 x 4.5, 0.55 x 3.5

[image: Group Box with radios--7]
[image: Button--7]

The problem is basically that on the different OS's, the group box has its proportions changed differently than the radios it contains, such that radios and labels that fit fine in the group box in XP run out of bounds (both x & y axis) on 7. Similarly, the text on the button grew more than the button. This happens even when I dial down the 7 box's resolution to match the XP box. The GroupBox's font is larger than that of the radios, but even when I made them equal I saw no improvement.

I think it has something to do with the fact that the application was originally created with an older version of C# and then ported. I say this because I just created a new (empty) Windows forms project using VS2008, and for every control in my app that isn't displaying correctly on win7, when I copy that control to the new app and run it on win7 it resizes correctly. There must be some high level property in the app that the controls are inheriting.

What causes this and what can I do about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a screen-shot perhaps? And I'm kind of leaning towards Accessibility features being enabled/altered, though can't confirm solely on what you're describing.

Comment: Added images to problem statement.

Comment: More likely a font/dpi issue. Using the layout mechanisms available (AutoSize, Anchors, Dock, layout containers, etc.) can usually solve those.

Comment: Added results of an experiment to the end of my problem statement.

Comment: Tergiver - the problem is too widespread. For example, a simple button with text anchored top/left is also experiencing this problem.

Comment: @Jim: Check the fonts in the original project. It's possible that they don't exist on Vista/Seven and the "closest match" being used isn't close enough.

Comment: @Tergiver - The font is Tahoma. I see it in the c:\windows\fonts folder of all 3 machines, although it is described as "TrueType" on XP, "OpenType" on Vista and as neither on 7. Don't know what that means if anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main form's 'AutoScaleMode' was set to 'Font'. Setting it to 'DPI' fixed it (although that created other problems due to the code not anticipating being resized on startup...null refs, but I can deal with those).

Tergiver gets double credit for pointing me to the form's property sheet and for me taking this long to notice the obvious property :)